# Issue dual booting windows 10 and ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

Sorry if this isn't the correct place for this post. I've looked at all the wiki, FAQ, and Windows Refugee places and didn't know where to post so forgive me if this isn't the correct place!

I'm trying to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu. Everything has been backed up and I've created a bootable USB with Rufus like the link told me to, when I restart and boot using the USB I get the Ubuntu boot options, but when I select the option to Install Ubuntu:

- the screen goes black for a second
- a streak of multi-colored squares runs across the top of the screen
- and then the screen goes black and just sits there, for a long time unless I manually restart the computer.

If someone could tell me why, and how to prevent the screen from hanging this point I would be very appreciative!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: I reverted the edit that introduced your follow-up question. Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? Appending more unrelated question to your original question is problematic because it may invalidate existing answers and makes new answers difficult because they'd have to answer both questions, one of which may be based on an solved or unreproducible issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your the image you loaded on your bootable pendrive has not been properly loaded. Try creating a fresh bootable USB drive using software such as "Win32DiskImager". Choose your Ubuntu ISO and just burn the image on the pendrive again. And try the installation again. Hopefully your hanging screen will go away!